# Android Room database - when all rows are loaded

Tags: android, database, android-room

I am trying to use Android Room described there: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#13
source codes: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/tree/kotlin/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/roomwordssample

I would like to choose one record when all records will be loaded.
I tried in the end of "onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)" function add this code:

```
        var rnd : Random = Random(System.currentTimeMillis())
        var words : List<Word>? = wordViewModel.allWords.value
        // now wordViewModel.allWords.value is NULL
        if (words != null) {
            var textViewRandomWord: TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
            textViewRandomWord.text = words.get(rnd.nextInt(words.size)).word
        }
```

But in this time is variable wordViewModel.allWords.value is still null.

Can you help me, where to add this code (or any similar code) to get random record from all saved records and show it when activity is created?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wordViewModel.allWords is [LiveData] : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata object, so its good to get value by observer

`wordViewModel.allWords.observe(this, Observer { words ->
           // Do your implementation
 })`